# ASP.NET Boilerplate change EmailSettingNames

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, constants, aspnetboilerplate

According to the documentation on [Email Sending](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Email-Sending):

> Email Sender uses setting management system to read email sending
>   configuration. All setting names are defined in
>   Abp.Net.Mail.EmailSettingNames class as constant strings.

I need pointers on how to override these default settings for values and use my own.

I save my settings in the Settings table too, but I do not use the name "Abp.Net.Mail.DefaultFromAddress", I use something like "Tenant.DefaultFromAddress".

If possible, I want to override only the email settings without tampering with other Abp settings.

Thank you.

## Clarification

My objective was to find a way to override these settings and use a different naming convention in the Settings table because the requirements of my application dictates that I do.

I just want it to be called differently but behave the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My objective was to find a way to override these settings and use a different naming convention in the Settings table

It takes more than a few lines.

1. Implement your own [EmailSettingNames](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/76107f600f70f98012db9d6e7e3a7629cd5b46cc/src/Abp/Net/Mail/EmailSettingNames.cs):

   ```
   public static class MyEmailSettingNames
   {
       public const string DefaultFromAddress = "Tenant.DefaultFromAddress";
       public const string DefaultFromDisplayName = "Tenant.DefaultFromDisplayName";

       public static class Smtp
       {
           public const string Host = "Tenant.Smtp.Host";
           public const string Port = "Tenant.Smtp.Port";
           public const string UserName = "Tenant.Smtp.UserName";
           public const string Password = "Tenant.Smtp.Password";
           public const string Domain = "Tenant.Smtp.Domain";
           public const string EnableSsl = "Tenant.Smtp.EnableSsl";
           public const string UseDefaultCredentials = "Tenant.Smtp.UseDefaultCredentials";
       }
   }
   ```
2. Implement your own [EmailSettingProvider](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/0a5813bd3e5bcad00a03fd0c7ac6965e320adbd9/src/Abp/Net/Mail/EmailSettingProvider.cs):

   ```
   internal class MyEmailSettingProvider : SettingProvider
   {
       public override IEnumerable<SettingDefinition> GetSettingDefinitions(SettingDefinitionProviderContext context)
       {
           return new[]
           {
               new SettingDefinition(MyEmailSettingNames.Smtp.Host, "127.0.0.1", L("SmtpHost"), scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant),
               new SettingDefinition(MyEmailSettingNames.Smtp.Port, "25", L("SmtpPort"), scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant),
               new SettingDefinition(MyEmailSettingNames.Smtp.UserName, "", L("Username"), scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant),
               new SettingDefinition(MyEmailSettingNames.Smtp.Password, "", L("Password"), scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant),
               new SettingDefinition(MyEmailSettingNames.Smtp.Domain, "", L("DomainName"), scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant),
               new SettingDefinition(MyEmailSettingNames.Smtp.EnableSsl, "false", L("UseSSL"), scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant),
               new SettingDefinition(MyEmailSettingNames.Smtp.UseDefaultCredentials, "true", L("UseDefaultCredentials"), scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant),
               new SettingDefinition(MyEmailSettingNames.DefaultFromAddress, "", L("DefaultFromSenderEmailAddress"), scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant),
               new SettingDefinition(MyEmailSettingNames.DefaultFromDisplayName, "", L("DefaultFromSenderDisplayName"), scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant)
           };
       }

       private static LocalizableString L(string name)
       {
           return new LocalizableString(name, MyLocalizationSourceName);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Implement your own [SmtpEmailSenderConfiguration](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/539a9b9029ef3cab2c22356bf299e225539d37c5/src/Abp/Net/Mail/Smtp/SmtpEmailSenderConfiguration.cs):

   ```
   public class MySmtpEmailSenderConfiguration : EmailSenderConfiguration, ISmtpEmailSenderConfiguration, ITransientDependency
   {
       public virtual string Host => GetNotEmptySettingValue(MyEmailSettingNames.Smtp.Host);
       public virtual int Port => SettingManager.GetSettingValue<int>(MyEmailSettingNames.Smtp.Port);
       public virtual string UserName => GetNotEmptySettingValue(MyEmailSettingNames.Smtp.UserName);
       public virtual string Password => GetNotEmptySettingValue(MyEmailSettingNames.Smtp.Password);
       public virtual string Domain => SettingManager.GetSettingValue(MyEmailSettingNames.Smtp.Domain);
       public virtual bool EnableSsl => SettingManager.GetSettingValue<bool>(MyEmailSettingNames.Smtp.EnableSsl);
       public virtual bool UseDefaultCredentials => SettingManager.GetSettingValue<bool>(MyEmailSettingNames.Smtp.UseDefaultCredentials);

       public MySmtpEmailSenderConfiguration(ISettingManager settingManager)
           : base(settingManager)
       {
       }
   }
   ```
4. Configure these in the `PreInitialize` method of [YourProjectNameCoreModule](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/master/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Core/AbpProjectNameCoreModule.cs#L36):

   ```
   Configuration.Settings.Providers.Add<MyEmailSettingProvider>();
   Configuration.ReplaceService<ISmtpEmailSenderConfiguration, MySmtpEmailSenderConfiguration>(DependencyLifeStyle.Transient);
   ```

Comment: I get this error for the ReplaceService.
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0308 The non-generic method 'IAbpStartupConfiguration.ReplaceService(Type, Action)' cannot be used with type arguments.

Comment: `using Abp.Configuration.Startup;`